# hibernate.ogm.datastore.create_database not working for MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, hibernate, hibernate-ogm

I am trying a simple Mongo DB and Hibernate OGM example. Here is my `persistence.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="mongo-ogm" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
  <provider>org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence</provider>
    <class>com.test.Employee</class>
    <properties>
      <!-- <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossStandAloneJtaPlatform"/> -->
      <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider" value="mongodb"/>
      <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.database" value="mongotest"/>
      <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.create_database" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.host" value="mymongo"/>
      <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.port" value="1234"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

In the logs, I see

`INFO: OGM001206: Mongo database named [mongotest] is not defined. Creating it!`

I expect that the database `mongotest` should be created in Mongo DB after the application boots up.. but it does not show up when I execute `show dbs` in Mongo. Also, my JPA based create (`em.persist`) does not throw any errors - I am not sure what's happening behind the scenes. This is fat JAR based setup (not a Java EE WAR)

Comment: It's normal. MongoDB does not actually create either a database namespace or a collection until you actually write something to it. Once you actually write some data, then you will see both database and collection exist.

Comment: Ok thanks for confirming. But I tried this as well i.e. used `EntityManager.persist()` to create a record - no error. I was expecting the collection to get created - but neither do I see the database nor the collection. Guess I am missing something, but not sure what

Answer (score 1):

Ok my bad.. Spoilt by the implicit Java EE transaction management ! This is a plain Java SE application and my create logic was missing transaction demarcation i.e. I added `em.getTransaction().begin();` before calling `persist` and added `em.getTransaction().commit();` after that and I can see the expected results